# ASP forms on HTML sites

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a static HTML website. I wish to add a couple of ASP .net web forms to display data from a data source. Is it possible to just develop an asp web form in VS and place it in a folder location on my site. Then I am planning to have a link to the web form filename. Does anybody know if this is possible without say a web config and a login page etc.

The form will be stand alone and the only asp page on the site.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you want to do??

Comment: I have been charged with binding data to a html page. In the interests of security i did not want to use a client side scripting language with a hard coded connection string. The site is ancient and is comprised of html documents. I wanted to add a couple of asp web forms which you could navigate to from one of the html pages using a simple anchor tag. Not sure if this would work and i am unable to test for a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 0):

- add this code in your html **<%** *Put Your Asp Form Code Here* **%>**